# Replace files content in VS code using Regex with original text

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have hundreds of files with different content like as

```
public delete(entity: Model1): Observable<any> {

public delete(entity: ModelABC): Observable<any> {
```

and I want to add one more parameter in the method like as below using VS code replace:

```
public delete(entity: Model1, simulate: boolean): Observable<any> {

public delete(entity: ModelABC, simulate: boolean): Observable<any> {
```

I have tried with below expression. but, It does not work correctly.
[image: Regex vs code]

Any solution? How can I replace all the matching line with correct replacement?

Comment: You need to capture the value you want to repeat `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and captured value references start at `$1`.  so find: `public delete\(entity: ([A-Za-z0-9]+)\): Observable<any> \{` replace: `public delete(entity: $1, simulate: boolean): Observable<any> {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one helped me to replace all the files with new parameter:

[image: Replace file content with regex]

Answer (score 1):

two error here :

- First you need to catch the part you want to reuse with parenthesis.
- Second, catch group starts from $1. ($0 contains the original match)

So, to do what you want, you'll need something like :

[image]